# Unexpected ID offset in tables after transaction

Tags: php, mysql

Ive basically done a transaction in two different functions, in my code which are called back to back. The code is written entirely in PHP using MySQL.

```
insert_into_table1()
{
     // transact start
     // perform delete from table1
     // insert into table from select statement from the database
     // commit if done, else rollback
}

insert_into_table2()
{
     // transact start
     // perform delete from table2
     // insert into table data from table1 after some processing (but same number of rows)
     // commit if done, else rollback
}
```

The above is an example of the psuedo-code.
**Initially, tables are empty.** 
The issue arises, after the code runs. Both tables get inserted with N number of rows.

When the code is run again, the tables are emptied using the delete command (MySQL). And N number of rows are inserted again into both tables.

But after the second (or more) run, the 'id' (I have this on auto_increment with offset 1 for both tables. Ive confirmed that the value doesn't change) field of table1 continues with N+1, but there is an offset of 10 for the second table whereas it should also continue with N+1.

I would like to know why this behavior occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: It would be slightly easier to help you find the reason/eventual bugs if you showed us the actual code, not a stripped down, pseudo-boilerplate-code that tells us nothing...

Comment: `rollback if done` so nothing is committed?

Comment: Are you sure you have `auto_increment` on both tables? and you're performing `delete` not `truncate`?

Comment: @jedifans Made the change, sorry.

Comment: @Shaharyar Yeah. I have `auto_increment` on both tables and i use delete. But after the delete is performed, there is an offset in table2, but no offset in table 1. The code for deletion and insertion is basically the same for both.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know it would be easier to show the actual code, but there are different functions being used from different files and classes, and showing it all would just make it more complicated to explain etc.

Comment: Sure, but your current post can basically be summed up as: "There's something strange happening when I run my code...  I won't show it to you but why does it happen?". We can guess and guess.. but that's not really helpful.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson At this point, even guesses are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert, the auto increment value increases. When you delete, it doesn't roll back.

A `TRUNCATE` of the table will reset it too but you still lose all data in the table.

Fine in your case as they are empty to begin with... but can you always guarantee that?

Comment: Agreed. It doesnt rollback when you delete. So both tables should continue from the last incremented value, right? This happens for table1 but not table2. And there are no other actions being performed in the tables. Just the deletes and inserts. 

So, there shouldnt be this offset at all. But there is an offset.

Comment: As long as `TRUNCATE` isn't done, the auto_increment must continue from the next value right? But for some reason, table2 shows an offset when it shouldn't

Comment: Perhaps you should print out the last insert ID after each insertion.